Saving Tabulator row state data for persistence
I have a Tabulator 6.3 page I am building to display data from ValKey. I'm trying to figure out how to save certain aspects of the table. My data is sorted by groups. Each row has a radio button and only one row per group can have this radio button enabled. There are also two other buttons in each row that essentially act as a checkbox, but a row can only have one checkbox checked. To clarify, I'm not talking about saving data back to ValKey per se. I can already do that. This is about saving the temporary state of the table as it relates to the rows of data.
I looked into the data persistence features of Tabulator. It save stuff like sorting, filtering, column resizing etc., and while it does have the ability to extend this, I'm not sure if my use case is a good fit for this, as it seems to be meant for columns, not rows. I also looked at the Reactive Data module a bit. That might be useful but I'm still looking into it. I just want to leverage what Tabulator already offers as much as I can before I code my own solution. I'd appreciate any suggestions or feedback.
